# polynomial with integer coefficients divided by $x^3 -x$

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Assume that 3 divides the value of $f(n)$ for each integer $n$. prove that when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^3-x $ , the remainder is of the form
$3r(x)$, where $r(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

[Source: ISI BMath UGA 2010](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4297_2010_isi_bmath_entrance_exam)

Comment: its supposed to x^3 -x... I made a typo

Comment: click on "edited ...ago" and you will see what is the difference with your original post, put your maths between $$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\pi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ be the natural quotient map, and write $\overline{f} := \pi(f)$. By your hypothesis, $\overline{f}$ has 3 roots. Hence
$$
\overline{f} = \overline{ax(x-1)(x+1)} = \overline{a(x^3-x)}
$$
Hence
$$
f(x) - a(x^3-x) \in \ker(\pi) = 3\mathbb{Z}[x]
$$
which is what you want.